# When looking for list of valid switches in dos help. Why is it sometimes /? command instead of help as I see no difference in DOS

Tags: windows, cmd, console

What's the difference between using CMD's help command and "?".  I couldn't find any difference but I did get it wrong in the CompTI A+.  The questions states "How can you see a list of valid switches for the cd command?  answer options are Type CD help which I chose and the correct one is Type cd /?.  The Explanation is:  To see detailed information about a specific command, type the command followed by /?.  Sometimes you can also use help followed by the command to get information about the command.  I tried both and they produce the same list of valid switches and tried it on other commands.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the sequence of words.

> "answer options are Type **CD help** which I chose"

That answer is "CD help" that will change to a directory called help, as opposed to "help CD" which will run the help program passing CD as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Both should work [equally well for system commands](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490917.aspx). The only functional difference is that one asks the `help` command for information about a certain topic, the other asks the `cd` command to output help. As both are created by the same company it would make little sense to display different information.

A notable limitation of using `help` is that this tool is only available on MS-DOS 5 and up - and that, by its design, cannot display information on programs it does not know (whereas most programs follow the convention to print help when started with the appropriate command line parameter).